# How to take out the numbers from the String and eliminate those number and store the filtered String and print it in java

Tags: java, string, numbers

```java
String txt = "d89%l++5r19o7W *o=1645le9H"
System.out.println(t.replace(/\\d{0,}/g,''));
```

Comment: Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. You want others to spent their time to help you with your problem, so you please spend the time required to come up with a clear question that we can actually help with.

Comment: `replace()` is simple substring substitution. You need to call `replaceAll()` to use regex.

Answer (score 1):

Because i'm bored...

```
String txt = "d89%l++5r19o7W *o=1645le9H";
txt = txt.replaceAll("\\d", "")
System.out.println(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will all numerical charactors from string

```
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("\\d",""));
```